# Time between connecting flights (separate tickets) at CDG

Tags: transit, cdg

I am flying to CDG with WOW. The airplane arrives at Terminal 1 at 11:30 AM (stats say that usually not later than 12:15 PM). Assuming it will land no later than that, what is the earliest time I can take a domestic flight from terminal 2F on a separate ticket? Do I have to get completely out of the airport? I guess I have to enter EU first. Is there automatic passport control at CDG (like the one in FRA)?

Thanks!

Comment: WOW is an Icelandic airline, right? Their hub is Keflavik; but where are you flying _from_ if you think you need to go through passport controls arriving in Paris?

Comment: Note there there is no such thing as "enter EU" for passport-control purposes. Immigration and passports is the matter of the Schengen area, which contains some, but not all, EU member states, as well as a few countries that are not EU members. Iceland is one of the latter countries.

Comment: Ah, ok, so if I do not have checked luggage I can just go shortest path to the gate for the next flight? (Assuming I do online check-in)

Comment: Whether you need to clear passport control dependson where you'rearriving from and where you're departing to.

Comment: I fly from Iceland to CDG and continue inside France.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iceland to France is Schengen-internal, so you won't need to cross immigration controls.

However, you can't walk between terminals 1 and 2 at CDG.

There are airside transfer shuttles, but at Terminal 1 they serve only the non-Schengen transit area which you won't reach with your itinerary.

You'll need to go landside at terminal 1 and then take the [CDGVAL peoplemover](http://www.parisaeroport.fr/en/passengers/access/paris-charles-de-gaulle/inter-terminal-shuttles) to terminal 2F and pass through security again. CDGVAL should not take more than 15 minutes, including wait time, but there are scattered reports of occasional very long security lines. With a non-guaranteed connection I would want to leave terminal 1 at least 1½ hours before scheduled departure, and I wouldn't feel halfway comfortable unless I had 2½. Add another 20 minutes for flights departing from terminals 2E (rows L and M) and 2G as they require another bus or peoplemover transfer after security.

Comment: It also varies depending OP has luggage to collect or not. The CDGVAL itself is quick getting there and from there is the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a later flight and have 3 hours time.

Comment: @erkil1452 I'd add that since you are arranging your own connection, you are responsible if your first flight is late and you miss the second one. 3 hours is a fair amount of time, but you should be prepared to seek alternate transportation if there are significant delays.

Comment: @ZachLipton Sure, Europe is small, I can just walk:-)